# Torus $T=\text{Spec}(K[M])$ for the character lattice $M=\{(a_0,....,a_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}\mid \sum_{i=0}^na_i=0\}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, toric-varieties

For $N=M=\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $e_0,...,e_n$ standard basis of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ the torus $T=\text{Spec}(K[M])=\text{Spec}(K[x_1^{\pm 1},...,x_n^{\pm 1}])=\mathbb{G}_m^n$, where $x_i=\chi^{e_i}$ with character lattice $M$.

Can someone explain me why I get the torus $T=\text{Spec}(K[M])=\mathbb{G}_m^{n+1}/\mathbb{G}_m$ for the character lattice $M=\{(a_0,....,a_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}\mid \sum_{i=0}^na_i=0\}$. The lattice of one-parameter subgroups in this case is $N=\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}/\mathbb{Z}(1,1,...,1)$.

$$\text{Is }\mathbb{G}_m^{n+1}/\mathbb{G}_m=\mathbb{P}^n\backslash \bigcup_{i=0}^nV(x_i)?$$

Thank you in advance.

I try to understand: (Fulton, Introduction to toric varieties)

> [image: enter preformatted text here]

Comment: Why do you define $K[M]:=K[x_i^{\pm 1}]$?

Comment: For $x_i=\chi^{e_i}$. You can also say $(K[\mathbb{Z}^n])$ is isomorphic to $K[x_i^{\pm 1}]$.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant $\mathbb{G}_m^{n+1}/\mathbb{G}_m$. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

When you write in Q1 the following: "Is Gnm/Gm=Pn∖⋃ni=0V(xi)?" one could quess there is some type of quotient construction. But dim(Gnm/Gm)=n−1 and the open set Pn−∪V(xi) has dimension n. What "quotient" are you considering in Q1?

Given any abelian group (scheme ) $G$ over $k$, the character group is defined as $Hom_{grp}(G, \mathbb{G}_{m,k})$, where $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}:=Spec(k[t,1/t])$. Which group $G$ are you considering above? You get

$$Hom_{grp}(\mathbb{G}_{a,k}^n,\mathbb{G}_{m,k}) \cong Hom_{k-alg}(k[t,1/t], k[x_1,..,x_n]) \cong k^*.$$

The units in $k[x_i]$ are $k^*$.

It seems there is a well defined map (everything has to be written out in terms of quotients)

$$\rho: \mathbb{G}_{m,k}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n- \cup_i V(x_i)$$

defined by

$$\rho(a_0,..,a_n):=[a_0: \cdots : a_n].$$

There is an action $\sigma: \mathbb{G}_{m,k} \times \mathbb{G}_{m,k}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_{m,k}^{n+1}$ defined by

$$\sigma(u,a):=\sigma(u,(a_0,..,a_n)):=(ua_0,..,ua_n),$$

and $\rho$ "factors": $\rho(\sigma(u,a))=\rho(a)$. In your question you do not specify what you are talking about and what maps you are studying. You should write down all definitions more precisely. Then it will be easier to answer your questions.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant $\mathbb{G}_m^{n+1}/\mathbb{G}_m$. I changed it.

Comment: I am considering the torus $T$ as the group scheme.

Comment: @Mandarine - you have defined the torus in two ways: as a quotient and in another way.

Comment: For example if $N=M=\mathbb{Z}^2$ and I have a fan $\Delta$ with 2-dimensional cones $\sigma_0=$pos$(e_1,e_2)$, $\sigma_1$=pos$(-e_1-e_2,e_2)$ and $\sigma_1=$pos$(e_1,-e_1-e_2)$ together with $\sigma_i\cap\sigma_j$ for $i\ne j$ and the origin. The toric variety $X(\Delta)$ is covered by $U_{\sigma_i}=\text{Spec}(K[M\cap \sigma^\vee])$ and can be identified with the affine opens $\mathbb{P}^2\backslash V(x_i)$. The torus belongs to the cone $\{0\}$ so I thought it must be $T=\text{Spec}(K[M])=\mathbb{G}_m^n$.

Comment: @Mandarine - it is better if you write a more detailed question where you explain the notation and where the problem originates.

Comment: The same construction should work for a fan in $\mathbb{R}^3/\mathbb{R}(1,1,1)$ where the lattice is $N=\mathbb{Z}^3/\mathbb{Z}(1,1,1)$ and the dual is $M=\{(a_0,a_1,a_2)\mid \sum_ia_i=0\}$. But in this case the torus has to be $\text{Spec}(K[M])=\mathbb{G}_m^3/\mathbb{G}_m$. But I don't understand why. Of course $\mathbb{G}_m^2\cong\mathbb{G}_m^3/\mathbb{G}_m$